# building for iOS, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am building an iOS App using a personal C++ library *mylib.a* , With the current Xcode version (13.1) When I include this library in my Frameworks and try to run on physical iOS device I have the following issue :

> building for iOS, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, for architecture arm64

When I include my library built with a previous XCode version (I think it was Xcode 11) the app builds and runs on the device.

The issue appears both on Mac intel and M1.

Answer (score -1):

You can try and exlude architectures or add a user defined setting called "VALID_ARCHS" in targets build settings[enter image description here][1]

look at image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAkWm.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried in build settings :
 - Exclude architecture arm64 for Any IOS Simulator for Debug and Release
 - Set the Supported Platform to iphoneos only
 - Set Architectures on $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and set Build Active Architecture Only on to YES

But it's not working

Comment: Make sure that there is also an excluded architecture, as it may get confused.